# Learning PureMVC: Any good basic tutorial/example?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, model-view-controller, puremvc

Again, I'm here looking for your wisdom, in this case, I need to learn PureMVC ASAP.

Thing is, at work all my programmer teammates use PureMVC in a flex webapp, the app is pretty huge and when I have to implement something/fix a bug/look some code, and I ask for help from another mate, he speaks about notifications, proxy, mediator.. and its like he speaks chinesse.

So, to put a stop to this situation, I need to learn this thing ASAP, in my free time.

I looked for a good guide or tutorial, but I couldn't find something basic and introductory, do you guys know one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is a good intro, gets you through the basics

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/understanding-the-puremvc-open-source-framework/

And, like always with any framework, check out their docs on their main website as well.